# how kotlin open a file with onclick button

Tags: android, kotlin

I wanted to open the file in kotlin.

Most of the code use `startActivityForResult` but it is deprecated.

so found this [one](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-open-a-specific-folder-via-intent-in-android/)

```
 // get reference to button
    val btn_csv_me = findViewById(R.id.btnCSV) as Button
    // set on-click listener
    btn_csv_me.setOnClickListener(object : View.OnClickListener {
      override fun onClick(view: View?) {
        val path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/" + "Downloads" + "/"
        val uri: Uri = Uri.parse(path)
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK)
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "*/*")
        startActivity(intent)
      }
    })

Uri  = /storage/emulated/0/Downloads/
```

but, it not show me to open with folder.
I just got 2 options : open with photo or contact.

Am I missing something here?

**EDIT:**

```
 // get reference to button
    val btn_csv_me = findViewById(R.id.btnCSV) as Button
    // set on-click listener
    btn_csv_me.setOnClickListener(object : View.OnClickListener {
      override fun onClick(view: View?) {
        val path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).toString()
        val uri: Uri = Uri.parse(path)
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "*/*")
        resultLauncher.launch(intent)   
      }

      private val resultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) {
        if (it.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
          val uri: Uri? = it.data?.data
          // Use this Uri
        }
      }
    })
```

thanks to Sohaib. now it did go to Download directory, but when i clic the file, it show me can not be shown.

i don't want to do that, just want to get the csv file and put it into sqlite later.

how can i get the name of the file please ?

Comment: You are welcome, can you try `Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT`?

Comment: yes i have tried, i got the value of uri : /document/document%3A206 not exactly the my csv file

Comment: No you got a nice content scheme of which you took only the path part. Use the whole uri. It starts with content:// and ends with the path you mentioned.

Comment: yes the uristring : content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/document%3A206 but still no my csv file : test.csv

Answer (score 1):

try this code.

```
private fun onButtonClick() {
    val path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).toString()
    val uri: Uri = Uri.parse(path)
    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
    intent.setDataAndType(uri, "*/*")
    resultLauncher.launch(intent)
}
```

Deprecated `startActivityForResult` has been replaced with `registerForActivityResult` as follow:

```
private val resultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) {
    if (it.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        val uri: Uri? = it.data?.data
        // Use this Uri
    }
}
```